# Spring Boot Filter can't get custom request header

Tags: reactjs, typescript, spring-boot

I'am trying to get a custom request header from client in spring filter
But even when I log all the headers, I still can't find the "userId" header

This is my filter and it work good

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    AuthRequestWrapper authRequestWrapper = new AuthRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest);
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    Enumeration<String> headerNames = httpRequest.getHeaderNames();
    if (headerNames != null) {
        while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            String name = headerNames.nextElement();
            Syssem.out.println("Header: " + name + " value:" + httpRequest.getHeader(name));
        }
    }

}
```

At client, I perform a request like this:

```
let credentials: RequestCredentials = "omit"
        let mode: RequestMode = 'cors'
        let headers: HeadersInit = {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:8080",
            "userId":"ABCD"
        }
```

```
const fetchOption = {
            method: 'GET', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
            credentials: credentials, // include, *same-origin, omit
            headers: headers,
            mode: mode, // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
        }
```

```
let responseObj = await (await fetch(finalUrl,fetchOption)).json()
```

I can still get the request header in Spring Controller.

Comment: There is no `userId` header, at least I see it nowhere being added in the client code. Also your filter is flawed as it stops processing at the end you should call `filterChain.doFilter(authRequestMapper, response);` else it breaks the application.

Comment: @M.Deinum I just forgot to put the "userId" header in the question but I am quite sure that it worked in my project and the Controller can receive the header

Comment: So you posted a dumbed down version of the code instead of the actual code? Your filter simply cannot work as the processing would stop after logging, so this isn't the actual filter you are using. Nonetheless if you don't receive the header the header simply isn't there and thus not being send from the client to the server.

Comment: @M.Deinum If you mentioned `filterChain.doFilter(authRequestMapper, response);`, I confirm that without it, the program still run. But after add it in, there still nothing happen.

Comment: Sr but turn out the filter work on another url pattern which I didn't expect to receive the header. The problem are solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try to another key of the header. For ex: `x-access-token`: {value}